# nginx redirect http to https in proxy ssl

Tags: nginx

this is my current nginx configuration :

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name upload.expert;
  proxy_set_header Host upload.expert;
  location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://upload.expert$1 permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name upload.expert;
  proxy_set_header Host upload.expert;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

https site working without problem, http return ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, what is wrong ?

real site : http://upload.expert and https://upload.expert

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect (with request uri) like this:

```
server {
      listen *:80;
      server_name upload.expert;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
      listen *:443 ssl;
      server_name upload.expert;
      proxy_set_header Host upload.expert;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      }
    }
```